# Check for empty instance of a class

Tags: matlab

I have a class with an empty constructor to support array creation. Suppose:

```
classdef MyClass < handle

  properties
    input1 = 0;
  end
  methods
  function obj = MyClass(input1)
    if nargin > 0
      obj.input1 = input1
    end
  end
  end
end
```

And I create a empty array of this class:

```
emptyArray(666) = MyClass
```

Then I fill some of the emptyArray indexes with full MyClass instances. Is there a matlab function to check if MyClass function is the same as the MyClass instance? Otherwise, how do I check if:

```
emptyArray==MyClass
```

to know the indexes in which the emptyArray contains empty instances of MyClass.

Thanks.

Note: It is a handle class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you consider overloaind `isempty` method for this class?

```
function tf = isempty( obj )
    tf = isempty( obj.input1 );
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately my true class has several properties. I could check for them separately, but if there was an easier way it would be better x)

Comment: @Werner how about adding a property `empty` that is set, by default, to `true` and is changed to `flase` otherwise?

Comment: In fact, I searched my class and there is one property called samples that has the value 0 when the class is empty. So I did: 


`input = [obj.samples];
tf = input == 0;`

And it returns true for the values in which are empty. Thank you!